# Xsd redefine complexType

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have 2 xsds.

I'm trying to redefine some complex type from 1 xsd in the second one.

But I get validation error on the redefinition.

I can't understand why.

The First Xsd (ConfigProperties.xsd):

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://example.com/configProperties" targetNamespace="http://example.com/configProperties" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="config-properties">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="System"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="System">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PushMessageFields" type="PushMessageFields"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="PushMessageFields"/>
</xs:schema>
```

The Second Xsd (SomeConfigProperties.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://example.com/SomeConfigProperties"  targetNamespace="http://example.com/SomeConfigProperties"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">


    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="ConfigProperties.xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="PushMessageFields">
          <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="PushMessageFields">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

I get the error in the second XSD: "cannot resolve the name 'PushMessageFields' ".

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't resolve the name because it can't find a `PushMessageFields` in the `http://example.com/SomeConfigProperties` namespace. There is none. You can't redefine types from a different target namespace.

Unless you have other errors, it should work if you change the target namespace of your new stylesheet to match the target namespace of the imported one. In your second XSD replace:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://example.com/SomeConfigProperties"   
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/SomeConfigProperties"   ... >
```

with

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://example.com/configProperties"  
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/configProperties"  ...>
```

Comment: Thx. Your suggestion works. But I have some necessity that those 2 xsds will be in different namespace.  Maybe there is another way redefine this complexType?

Comment: Not using `redefine`. If you place `PushMessageFields` in another namespace, it won't be found by the original XSD. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to override the PushMessageFields from the configPropertiea.xsd.

Comment: But why do you need the namespaces to be different? The best you can do with different namespaces is `import`. But you can't make `System` accept a `PushMessageFields` from another namespace.

Comment: OK! Got your point. It is too complicated for me to explain why I need different namespaces. Thanks very much for your answers though.